# How to use different connection strings based on sub domain in .net core

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-core, subdomain, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building a website where I have one master site. This is connected to SQL. This site must have many sub-domains. Each sub-domain must have his own DocumentDB connectionstring as well as the master connection string. Is this possible .Net Core? And if so, how can I achieve this goal?

I allready search for solutions but can't find somethin use full.

[image]

This is how I see the big picture. Please give me some advise on how to achieve this. Thank you!

**UPDATE**
The problem is, I want to store the connection strings for the DocumentDB in the master DB. So, when visit a subdomain, it must get DOcumentDB connection string form SQL and than get data from there.

**UPDATE 2**
I don't realy know how I can make my self clear. It's hard to explain cause there are many aspects I don't understand my self. Sorry for that.

I made a middleware know where I try to get the subdomain so i can give that back and use it. 
This is what I got so far.
My middleware:

```
public class ObtainSubdomainMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ObtainSubdomainMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var subDomain = string.Empty;

        var host = context.Request.Host.Host;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(host))
        {
            subDomain = host.Split('.')[0]; // How should I give back the subDomain?
        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        return this._next(context);
    }
}
```

And the startup class:

```
        //Here I think I have to do something with this middleware to use the right connectionstring
        app.UseMiddleware<ObtainSubdomainMiddleware>();
```

Comment: You can have as many connection strings as you want. What's the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail for your reaction, I didn't made my problem clear. Please check the update on my question.

Comment: Still unclear for me. What is the problem with scenario you described? Just read a string from master db, then add it to a cache (you don't want to hit a master db on each subdomain web request, right?), and then use that string to connect to document db.

Comment: please see my updated question. It's hard for me too explain the problem

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store the connection strings for the DocumentDB in the master DB. So, when visit a subdomain, it must get DOcumentDB connection string form SQL and than get data from there.

Firstly, you could try to access `HttpContext.Request.Host` directly inside your MVC controllers and query your SQL db to get the connection string based on subdomain name.

Secondly, if possible, you could publish your app as three separate website with its own subdomain and store and manage DocumentDB connection string in Web.config file. Users could browse the site and access different DocumentDB from different subdomains.